# finding equal values in 2 CSV files with python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have 2 excel files, each containing 2 columns like below:

file1:

```
name     price
a        1
b        78
f        54
g        32
t        2
```

file2:

```
name     price
f        4
x        23
e        76
a        4
o        0
```

I want to read `file1` and search for values where `file2` name is equal to `file1` name and extract prices, then write them in price column of `file2`.

`file2` should look like this:

file2:

```
name     price
f        54
x        23
e        76
a        1
o        0
```

I have tried as below (I've saved the excel files as CSV):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1  = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('file1.csv'))
df2  = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('file2.csv'))

if(df1[name] in df2[name]):
  df2[price] = df1[price]
  
df2.to_csv('file2.csv')
```

Comment: These look like TSV files maybe, not CSV. Can you please [edit] to clarify this, either by changing the delimiter to comma if that's what you actually have in the files, or else change the wording to not suggest that you have Comma-Separated Values format if you don't really. (Of course, if this misunderstanding is the cause of your problem, probably simply delete this question as unreproducible.)

Comment: Using Pandas and Numpy for simple file manipulation is severe overkill, though if you need them anyway for other reasons, I suppose they offer some limited additional conveniences over the Python standard library.

Comment: @tripleee what is the shortest way to do this? is there any way to manipulate csv files without converting them to df?

Comment: some syntax errors on your side `pd.read_csv` returns a `pd.DataFrame` object so no need to wrap it around `pd.read_csv` see the duplicate post it will be really helpful now and in future

Answer (score 0):

You need first to merge:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on='name', how='left')
```

Then you can use np.where:

```
import numpy as np
df2['price'] = np.where(df2['price_y'].isnull(), df2['price_x'], df2['price_y'])
```

Later you can delete the merged columns:

```
df2.drop(columns=['price_x', 'price_y'], inplace=True)
```

This is the result:

```
name     price
f        54
x        23
e        76
a        1
o        0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

use `combine_first`

```
df1.set_index('name').combine_first(df2.set_index('name'))\
   .reindex(df2['name']).reset_index()
```

It seems that questioner do not know about Pandas' `inplace`, so I will attach the output results as image.

[image]

other way : use `concat` & `groupby` + `last`

```
pd.concat([df2, df1]).groupby('name').last()\
  .reindex(df2['name']).reset_index()
```

same result

other way : `merge` & `pop`

```
df2.merge(df1, on='name', how='left', suffixes=['1', ''])\
   .assign(price=lambda x: x['price'].fillna(x.pop('price1')).astype('int'))
```

same result

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

file1 = '''name     price
a        1
b        78
f        54
g        32
t        2
'''

file2 = '''name     price
f        4
x        23
e        76
a        4
o        0
'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file1), sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(file2), sep='\s+')
```